# How to kill remote command — run via SSH — when SSH is terminated?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to run an infinite loop via SSH, e.g.

```
ssh remote_server "loop"
```

However, the process `loop` persists when I exit SSH with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Is there any way I can cause `loop` to terminate when SSH is terminated?

### An example

Let `loop` be the following file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Before terminating, `ps uxf` shows:

```
tshmak   177639  0.0  0.0 140768  4508 ?        S    10:06   0:00 sshd: tshmak@pts/0
tshmak   177640  0.0  0.0  14548  5220 pts/0    Ss   10:06   0:00  \_ -bash
tshmak   180067  0.0  0.0  29128  3068 pts/0    R+   11:45   0:00      \_ ps uxf
```

After terminating, I get:

```
tshmak   179490  0.0  0.0  12524  3036 ?        Ss   11:45   0:00 /bin/bash /home/tshmak/scripts/loop
tshmak   187387  0.0  0.0   7288   656 ?        S    11:47   0:00  \_ sleep 1
```

Comment: Hmm… Odd. A command run like that should just die when the SSH disconnects. What exactly is `loop`? A custom script? If it inherently runs in the background with something like `nohup [command] &` then it will persist even if the connection is lost. So my guess is something in that script is purposely keeping itself alive like that.

Comment: Hi @Giacomo1968, I've added an example to my question. Can you reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Boy. That is weird.

Comment: This is normal. `SIGHUP` is sent when the controlling terminal is closed. You didn't use `ssh -t` and therefore `loop` on the remote side has no controlling terminal, it never gets `SIGHUP`. What behavior do you want? (1) You run `loop` in some special way on demand, so it terminates when `ssh` exits. (2) You run `loop` normally (like in the question) and some global config makes it terminate when `ssh` exit.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Wow! Thanks for posting that about `-t` which I see the man page explains means: “Force pseudo-terminal allocation.” Makes complete sense now.

Comment: ... (3) You run `loop` normally (like in the question) and the script itself does something in order to exit when `ssh` exits (non-global solution).